# Alterar cores dos gráficos com chartjs

Tags: angularjs-directives, chartjs, angular-8

Galera, estou utilizando o ChartJs para criação de uma dashboard e queria mudar as cores dos gráficos. Achei a biblioteca Patternomaly que auxilia nessas alterações, mas não estou sabendo importar em um projeto angular.
Qual seria a melhor alternativa pra alterar as cores?
já tentei com backgroundColor fazendo um databinding mas não reconhece o backgroungColor como uma propriedade.

Minha div:

```
<div class="row">
    <section class="col l5 m12 s12 center-align">
      <h3>Registros de {{ date | date: 'yyyy'}}</h3>
      <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions"
        [plugins]="barChartPlugins" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" >
      </canvas>
    </section>
    <div class="col l2">
      <div class="">
```

Meu arquivo dashboard.component.ts

```
  //CHARTYPE BAR
  barChartLabels: Label[] = ['Cadastrados com sucesso', 'Cadastros incompletos'];
  barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  barChartLegend = true;
  barChartPlugins = [];

  barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [45, 37, 60, 70, 46, 33], label: 'Solicitações' }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhando na biblioteca, entendi como faria.
Dentro da própria declaração da variável do tipo ChartDataSets:

```
barChartLabels: Label[] = ['Cadastrados com sucesso', 'Cadastros incompletos'];
barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { 
     data: [45, 37, 60, 70, 46, 33], 
     label: 'Solicitações', 
     backgroundColor : ['#00BCD4', '#FF5252'] }
  ];
```